# Make row value into column and sum for DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

maybe this is easy, but I can't really figure it out on my own.

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    Date            Currency    Amount
0   2014-10-17      EUR         -20000000
1   2014-10-17      EUR         -80000000
2   2014-10-17      USD         -20000000
3   2014-10-18      JPY         -20000000
4   2014-10-19      USD         -10000000
5   2014-10-19      USD         -20000000
6   2014-10-20      JPY         -20000000
7   2014-10-20      JPY         -20000000
```

and want to make the currency tickers into column names and at the same time, sum all the amounts for each day, so result would look like:

```
    Date            EUR          USD          JPY
0   2014-10-17     -100000000   -20000000     0.0
1   2014-10-18      0.0          0.0         -20000000
2   2014-10-19      0.0         -30000000     0.0
3   2014-10-20      0.0          0.0         -40000000
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

either using [`.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table):

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Currency',
...                values='Amount', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
Currency          EUR       JPY       USD
Date                                     
2014-10-17 -100000000         0 -20000000
2014-10-18          0 -20000000         0
2014-10-19          0         0 -30000000
2014-10-20          0 -40000000         0
```

or, [`.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) followed by [`.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack), followed by [`.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna):

```
>>> df.groupby(['Date', 'Currency'])['Amount'].agg('sum').unstack().fillna(0)
Currency          EUR       JPY       USD
Date                                     
2014-10-17 -100000000         0 -20000000
2014-10-18          0 -20000000         0
2014-10-19          0         0 -30000000
2014-10-20          0 -40000000         0
```

Comment: Your second example could be simplified to `df.groupby(['Date', 'Currency']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)` as there is only one column in this case